# Why does slice value change?

Tags: go

The value of a slice that be appended to a two-dimension slice, is changed later。 Why does it happen?

The full code is below:

```
import "sort"
import "fmt"

func combinationSum(candidates []int, target int) [][]int {
    sort.Ints(candidates)
    var ret [][]int
    var curlist []int
    combinationSumRecursive(candidates, target, 0, curlist, &ret)
    fmt.Println("ret", ret)
    return ret
}

func combinationSumRecursive(candidates []int, target int, curCandidateIdx int, curlist []int, ret *[][]int) {
    if target == 0 {
        fmt.Println("put", curlist)
        *ret = append(*ret, curlist)
        return
    }
    for i:=curCandidateIdx;i<len(candidates);i++{
        if candidates[i] > target {
            break
        }
        combinationSumRecursive(candidates, target - candidates[i], i, append(curlist, candidates[i]), ret)
    }
}
```

INPUT is :

```
[7,3,2]
18
```

OUTPUT is below:

```
put [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
put [2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3]
put [2 2 2 2 3 7]
put [2 2 2 3 3 3 3]
put [2 2 7 7]
put [2 3 3 3 7]
put [3 3 3 3 3 3]
ret [[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2] [2 2 2 2 2 7 3 3] [2 2 2 2 3 7] [2 2 2 3 3 3 3] [2 2 7 7] [2 3 3 3 7] [3 3 3 3 3 3]]
```

The second slice in `ret` is changed. `[2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3]` was expected.

Thanks to any help.

Comment: The second slice was changed?  what does it mean? what's the question here?

Comment: When put slice into `ret`, it is `put [2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3]`, then second line in `OUTPUT`. But later print the `ret`, the second slice is `[2 2 2 2 2 7 3 3]`.

Comment: You are trying to find all combinations of `candidates` [0:N] that sum to `target`. Correct?

Comment: @RickyA Yes, the combinations can use duplicate candidates.

Comment: Tip: when a slice unexpectedly changes, it usually means you should have copied it somewhere. Also not assigning the value from `append` to the same variable as the first argument is prone to cause bugs (you can do it, but it's always one of the first things to check carefully)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the change of the slice `curlist` in the append on line `combinationSumRecursive(candidates, target - candidates[i], i, append(curlist, candidates[i]), ret)`.

A solution is to reassign `curlist` to the appended result before passing it to the next recursive level.

```
package main

import "sort"
import "fmt"

func combinationSum(candidates []int, target int) [][]int {
    sort.Ints(candidates)
    var ret [][]int
    var curlist []int
    combinationSumRecursive(candidates, target, 0, curlist, &ret)
    fmt.Println("ret", ret)
    return ret
}

func combinationSumRecursive(candidates []int, target int, curCandidateIdx int, curlist []int, ret *[][]int) {
    if target == 0 {
        fmt.Println("put", curlist)
        *ret = append(*ret, curlist)
        return
    }
    for i := curCandidateIdx; i < len(candidates); i++ {
        if candidates[i] > target {
            break
        }
        curlist = append(curlist, candidates[i])
        combinationSumRecursive(candidates, target-candidates[i], i, curlist, ret)
    }
}

func main() {
    combinationSum([]int{7, 3, 2}, 18)
}
```

This yields:

```
put [2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2]
put [2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3]
put [2 2 2 2 3 7]
put [2 2 2 3 3 3 3]
put [2 2 7 7]
put [2 3 3 3 7]
put [3 3 3 3 3 3]
ret [[2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2] [2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3] [2 2 2 2 3 7] [2 2 2 3 3 3 3] [2 2 7 7] [2 3 3 3 7] [3 3 3 3 3 3]]
```

[EDIT] First read [this](https://blog.golang.org/slices). That explains that although you see the addresses of the slice headers change the backing array can still be the same after an append.

Then [this](https://play.golang.org/p/UpRUCEtj83) is an example of what happens in your case.
The problem is in your case is it hard to see because of the recursive calls and the re positioning of the current index into `curlist`.

Comment: But, I print each curlist's address at first line of `combinationSumRecursive`, it show each curlist's address in each call of `combinationSumRecursive` is different.        e.g.:  `fmt.Printf("address of slice %p, value is %x \n", &curlist, curlist)`

Comment: And, why only the second slice has been changed.

Comment: You have stumbled on something interesting here. Somehow the `append` [internals](https://blog.golang.org/slices#TOC_10.) alter the contents when the `append` return is assigned to a new variable.

Comment: I am trying to get a mve running to send that to Dave Cheney, but no luck so far https://play.golang.org/p/9MVWoa6O-A

Comment: @RickyA: what does Dave have to do with basic slice usage?

Comment: @JimB: you are right, it all boils down to the backing slice arrays here. The recursive calls makes it hard to see what goes out of scope where.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the `curlist` only when `target==0` but it keeps changing due to the `append(curlist, candidates[i])` in your recursive function.
If you try with other candidates, for example : `[5,3,2]` you will notice that other slices change not only the second.

try making a copy of `curlist` when the `target=0`:

```
if target == 0 {
    fmt.Println("put", curlist)
    newCurlist := make([]int, len(curlist))
    copy(newCurlist, curlist)
    *ret = append(*ret, newCurlist)
    return
}
```

this should work!